# Java - Append quotes to strings in an array and join strings in an array

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

I would like to append double quotes to strings in an array and then later join them as a single string (retaining the quotes). Is there any String library which does this? I have tried Apache commons StringUtils.join and the Joiner class in Google guava but couldn't find anything that appends double quotes.

My input would be an array as mentioned below:

```
String [] listOfStrings = {"day", "campaign", "imps", "conversions"};
```

Required output should be as mentioned below:

```
String output = "\"day\", \"campaign\", \"imps\", \"conversions\"";
```

I know I can loop through the array and append quotes. But I would like a more cleaner solution if there is one.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

## With Java 8+

Java 8 has [`Collectors.joining()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) and its overloads. It also has [`String.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-).

#### Using a `Stream` and a `Collector`

**The naive but effective way**

```
String wrapWithQuotesAndJoin(List<String> strings) {
  return strings.stream()
    .map(s -> "\"" + s + "\"")
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

**Shortest and probably better performing** (somewhat hackish, though)

```
String wrapWithQuotesAndJoin(List<String> strings) {
  return strings.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\", \"", "\"", "\""));
}
```

#### Using `String.join`

Very hackish. Don't use. (but it must be mentioned)

```
String wrapWithQuotesAndJoin(List<String> strings) {
  return strings.isEmpty() ? "" : "\"" + String.join("\", \"", strings) + "\""
}
```

## With older versions of Java

Do yourself a favor and use a library. [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/) comes immediately to mind.

#### Using Guava

```
private static final Function<String,String> addQuotes = new Function<String,String>() {
  @Override public String apply(String s) {
    return new StringBuilder(s.length()+2).append('"').append(s).append('"').toString();
  }
};
String wrapWithQuotesAndJoin(List<String> strings) {     
    return Joiner.on(", ").join(Iterables.transform(listOfStrings, addQuotes));
}
```

#### No libraries

```
String wrapWithQuotesAndJoin(List<String> strings) {
  if (listOfStrings.isEmpty()) {
    return "";
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Iterator<String> it = listOfStrings.iterator();
  sb.append('"').append(it.next()).append('"'); // Not empty
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(", \"").append(it.next()).append('"');
  }
  result = sb.toString();
}
```

**Notes**:

- All the solutions assume that `strings` is a `List<String>` rather than a `String[]`. You can convert a `String[]` into a `List<String>` using `Arrays.asList(strings)`. You can get a `Stream<String>` directly from a `String[]` using `Arrays.stream(strings)`.
- The Java 8+ snippets use the `+` concatenation because at this point `+` is usually better performing than `StringBuilder`.
- The older-version snippets use `StringBuilder` rather than `+` because it's usually faster on the older versions.

Answer (score 13):

```
String output = "\"" + StringUtils.join(listOfStrings , "\",\"") + "\"";
```

Comment: parameters are reversed: `StringUtils.join("\",\"", listOfStrings)`

Comment: If the `listOfStrings` is empty then prints two quotes (`""`) that isn't acceptable for some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Add the quotes along with the separator and then append the quotes to the front and back.

```
"\"" + Joiner.on("\",\"").join(values) + "\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the code for this functionality yourself as well:

```
String output = "";

for (int i = 0; i < listOfStrings.length; i++)
{
    listOfStrings[i] = "\"" + listOfStrings[i] + "\"";
    output += listOfStrings[i] + ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String [] listOfStrings = {"day", "campaign", "imps", "conversions"};
    String output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfStrings.length; i++) {
        output += "\"" + listOfStrings[i] + "\"";
        if (i != listOfStrings.length - 1) {
            output += ", ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output: "day", "campaign", "imps", "conversions"

Comment: Sommes - StringUtils.join is a much cleaner solution. I wanted to know if any of the libraries have a functionality to append double quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method present in JDK which can do this, but you can use the [Apache Commons Langs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [StringUtls](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/) class , `StringUtils.join()` it will work

Comment: Himanshu - I am already using StringUtils.join. I would like to know how we can append the double quotes to the string. I am sorry for not being clear on that. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way would be sth. like:

```
private static class QuoteFunction<F> {
    char quote;

    public QuoteFunction(char quote) {
        super();
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    Function<F, String> func = new Function<F,String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(F s) {
            return new StringBuilder(s.toString().length()+2).append(quote).append(s).append(quote).toString();
        }
    };

    public Function<F, String> getFunction() {
        return func;
    }
}
```

... call it via the following function

```
public static <F> String asString(Iterable<F> lst, String delimiter, Character quote) {
    QuoteFunction<F> quoteFunc = new QuoteFunction<F>(quote);
    Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(delimiter).skipNulls();
    return joiner.join(Iterables.transform(lst, quoteFunc.getFunction()));
}
```